# R loop for simple regression

Tags: r, regression

I would like to create a function who can work with any data frame, with a minimum number of columns (1) and maximum number of columns (n). The function has to do a simple linear regression for each of the independent variables. I know that I have to use the loop for (.), but I don't know how to use it.
I try this, but it doesn't work:

```
>data1<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE,sep=",")
>n<-nrow(data1)
>PredictorVariables <- paste("x", 1:n, sep="")
>Formula <-paste("y ~ ", PredictorVariables, collapse=" + ",data=data1)
>lm(Formula, data=data1)
```

Comment: why the `javascript`, `android`, `python` and `iphone` tags?

Comment: If you want to use everything except `y` as a predictor, you can do `lm(y ~ ., data = data1)`.

Comment: i use javascript, android... because i had probleme with tags to publish my question.

Comment: the   lm(y ~ ., data = data1) doesent change anything i still havethe same probleme

Comment: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : objet 'y' introuvable

Comment: i have to introduce a for() loop but dont know how.

Comment: Is `y` the column name of the dependent variable in `data1`? I assumed it was because of the example code you showed. Replace `y` with the appropriate column name and try again.

Comment: no Y its not the column name in the data1, and i need to create something who can work whith any dataframe and any name of column.

Comment: Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post.

Comment: @jean-philippe Did you take a look at my solution below? The function `myfit` should do what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach with `lapply()`, using the `mtcars` data set. We will select`mpg` as the dependent variable, extract the remaining columns from the data set, and then use `lapply()` to run regression models on each element in the `indepVars` vector. The output from each model is saved to a list, including the name of the independent variable as well as the resulting model object.

```
indepVars <- names(mtcars)[!(names(mtcars) %in% "mpg")]

modelList <- lapply(indepVars,function(x){
     result <- lm(mpg ~ mtcars[[x]],data=mtcars)
     list(variable=x,model=result) 
})

# print the first model
modelList[[1]]$variable
summary(modelList[[1]]$model)
```

The extract operator `[[` can then be used to print the content of any of the models.

...and the output:

```
> # print the first model
> modelList[[1]]$variable
[1] "cyl"
> summary(modelList[[1]]$model)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ mtcars[[x]], data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.9814 -2.1185  0.2217  1.0717  7.5186 
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  37.8846     2.0738   18.27  < 2e-16 ***
mtcars[[x]]  -2.8758     0.3224   -8.92 6.11e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.206 on 30 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7262,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7171 
F-statistic: 79.56 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 6.113e-10

>
```

Responding to the comment from the original poster, here is the code necessary to encapsulate the above process within an R function. The function `regList()` takes a data frame name and a dependent variable string, and then proceeds to run regressions of the dependent variable on each of the remaining variables in the data frame passed to the function.

```
regList <- function(dataframe,depVar) {
     indepVars <- names(dataframe)[!(names(dataframe) %in% depVar)]
     
     modelList <- lapply(indepVars,function(x){
          message("x is: ",x)
          result <- lm(dataframe[[depVar]] ~ dataframe[[x]],data=dataframe)
          list(variable=x,model=result) 
     })
     modelList
}

modelList <- regList(mtcars,"mpg")
# print the first model
modelList[[1]]$variable
summary(modelList[[1]]$model)
```

One can extract a variety of content from the individual model objects.  The output is as follows:

```
> modelList <- regList(mtcars,"mpg")
> # print the first model
> modelList[[1]]$variable
[1] "cyl"
> summary(modelList[[1]]$model)

Call:
lm(formula = dataframe[[depVar]] ~ dataframe[[x]], data = dataframe)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.9814 -2.1185  0.2217  1.0717  7.5186 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     37.8846     2.0738   18.27  < 2e-16 ***
dataframe[[x]]  -2.8758     0.3224   -8.92 6.11e-10 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.206 on 30 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7262,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7171 
F-statistic: 79.56 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 6.113e-10

>
```

Comment: but 
I need a function that receives the following arguments: A dataframe, the column number of the response variable, the number of the minimum explanatory variable column, the number of the maximum explanatory variable column.
 for example: function1 (df, 1, 2,10) 1 is the column of the response variable, the explanatory variables are located on columns from 2 to 10 inclusively

Comment: The function makes a simple linear regression for the response variable and the set of explanatory variables of the dataframe individually (y ~ x1, y ~ x2, ... etc)
It returns the diagnostic charts for each of these regressions (2 rows, 2columns). The function must be applicable regardless of the data frame submitted as a generalizable argument to all dataframes

Comment: @jean-philippe - the additional context in your comments above should have been included in your question, along with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That said, I updated my answer to include an R function that allows one to specify a data frame name and a dependent variable name, rather than column numbers. The answer can easily be tweaked to use column numbers.

Comment: sorry, i am just beginner on R and its too difficult for me. your help is really appreciated.

Comment: i need something more general using column numbers to work with any name of the independent or dépendante variable in any data frame.

Comment: @jean-philippe - the function I posted, `regList()`, is already generalized. One passes a data frame name and dependent variable name as arguments to the function, and the function generates linear models for all other variables in the data frame. I simply used `mtcars` as an example, since you didn't post a verifiable example in your question.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

First, I create some sample data:

```
# Sample data
set.seed(2017);
x <- sapply(1:10, function(x) x * seq(1:100) + rnorm(100));
df <- data.frame(Y = rowSums(x), x);
```

Next I define a custom function:

```
# Custom function where
#  df is the source dataframe
#  idx.y is the column index of the response variable in df
#  idx.x.min is the column index of the first explanatory variable
#  idx.x.max is the column index of the last explanatory variable
# The function returns a list of lm objects
myfit <- function(df, idx.y, idx.x.min, idx.x.max) {
    stopifnot(idx.x.min < idx.x.max, idx.x.max <= ncol(df));
    res <- list();
    for (i in idx.x.min:idx.x.max) {
        res[[length(res) + 1]] <- lm(df[, idx.y] ~ df[, i]);
    }
    return(res);
}
```

Then I run `myfit` using the sample data.

```
lst <- myfit(df, 1, 2, 11);
```

The return object `lst` is a `list` of `11-2+1 = 10` fit results of class `lm`. For example,

```
lst[[1]];
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = df[, idx.y] ~ df[, i])
#
#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)      df[, i]
#     -5.121       55.100
```

---

### PS

For future posts I recommend having a look at [how to ask good questions here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and providing a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), *including sample data*.